# Change the "view cart" product overlay button on product loops in Woocommerce

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, product

Relatively new to WooCommerce and I'm trying to make a simple change to a button that appears after you have successfully added a product to the cart.

I am using Shop Isle and have created a child theme.

When you hover over a product an overlay appears that allows you to add a product to the basket. This button triggers an AJAX call which adds the product and on success it shows a new View Basket button.

From what I can tell this is being done by a Woocommerce file (not a theme specific one) and is handled in `add-to-cart.js` *(`js/frontend/add-to-cart.js`)*

What I want to do is change this text and the link to go directly to the checkout page.

The code I found is below:

```
if ( ! wc_add_to_cart_params.is_cart && $button.parent().find( '.added_to_cart' ).length === 0 ) 
{
    $button.after( ' <a href="' + wc_add_to_cart_params.cart_url + '" class="added_to_cart wc-forward" title="' +
    wc_add_to_cart_params.i18n_view_cart + '">' + wc_add_to_cart_params.i18n_view_cart + '</a>' );
}
```

I know I could simply overwrite the code here but it wouldn't be future proof when the plugin gets updated and even more importantly I'm not actually sure where the function is getting the `wc_add_to_cart_params` from and where I would even go about overwriting this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The right and cleanest way to change the text and URL from js "View cart" button is:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_script_data', 'change_js_view_cart_button', 10, 2 ); 
function change_js_view_cart_button( $params, $handle )  {
    if( 'wc-add-to-cart' !== $handle ) return $params;

    // Changing "view_cart" button text and URL
    $params['i18n_view_cart'] = esc_attr__("Checkout", "woocommerce"); // Text
    $params['cart_url']      = esc_url( wc_get_checkout_url() ); // URL

    return $params;
}
```

*Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme)*. Tested and works.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
function change_view_cart( $params, $handle )
{
            switch ($handle) {
                case 'wc-add-to-cart':
                    $params['i18n_view_cart'] = "Proceed to Cart"; //chnage Name of view cart button
                    $params['cart_url'] = "http://myshop.com/custom-page"; //change URL of view cart button
                break;
            }
            return $params;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_script_data', 'change_view_cart',10,2 );
```