# Change URL of “View Cart” button on WooCommerce Pages other than Cart and Checkout

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am applying the below code to change the URL of “View Cart” button on the Shop page.

```
// Change View Cart Button URL from /cart to /checkout
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect', 'cart_to_checkout' );
 
function cart_to_checkout( $url ) {
    return wc_get_checkout_url();
}
```

What is the filter that I need to use to achieve the same for “View Cart” button in the “Woocommerce error message” on the Single Product Page?

Woocommerce error message” appears something like this: “The maximum allowed quantity for ‘Product X’ is 3 (you currently have 3 in your cart). “View Cart”

So, I need to change the URL of the “View Cart” button in the above message.

And also, all the View Cart buttons must point to Checkout Page and not Cart Page.

Thanks!

Comment: Would this work for what you need?
`apply_filters( 'woocommerce_get_cart_url', wc_get_page_permalink( 'checkout' ))` Should essentially change the view cart page to always go to the checkout page

Comment: Thanks. But it didn't work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As this notice is hard coded in `WC_Cart` `add_to_cart()` method *([from line `1075` to `1083`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/4.3.0/includes/class-wc-cart.php#L1075-L1083))*:

```
throw new Exception(
    sprintf(
        '<a href="%s" class="button wc-forward">%s</a> %s',
        wc_get_cart_url(),
        __( 'View cart', 'woocommerce' ),
        /* translators: 1: quantity in stock 2: current quantity */
        sprintf( __( 'You cannot add that amount to the cart &mdash; we have %1$s in stock and you already have %2$s in your cart.', 'woocommerce' ), wc_format_stock_quantity_for_display( $product_data->get_stock_quantity(), $product_data ), wc_format_stock_quantity_for_display( $products_qty_in_cart[ $product_data->get_stock_managed_by_id() ], $product_data ) )
    )
);
```

The only way to change the url link is using [`woocommerce_get_cart_url`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/4.3.0/includes/wc-core-functions.php#L1438) filter hook [located inside the function `wc_get_cart_url()`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/4.3.0/includes/wc-core-functions.php#L1430-L1439) *(used in this notice)* as follow **for single product pages only**:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_cart_url', 'filter_get_cart_url' );
function filter_get_cart_url( $url ) {
    // Only on single product pages
    if( is_product() )
        $url = wc_get_checkout_url();
    
    return $url;
}
```

---

To change **all url links** that are using `wc_get_cart_url()` to checkout url, you will use instead:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_cart_url', 'wc_get_checkout_url' );
```

---

Addition: To make it work everywhere except on cart and checkout pages, use the following:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_cart_url', 'filter_get_cart_url' );
function filter_get_cart_url( $url ) {
    // Except on cart and checkout pages
    if( ! ( is_cart() || is_checkout() ) )
        $url = wc_get_checkout_url();
    
    return $url;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

---

Related: [Change the "view cart" product overlay button on product loops in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49431000/change-the-view-cart-product-overlay-button-on-product-loops-in-woocommerce)